# Sqlite Creates lot of dll files on tomcat temp folder

Tags: sqlite

i'm using Java 8, gradle, tomcat8 and Sqlite 3.8.11.2.

I installed sqlite on my project obviously using gradle.
All works fine, i dont have any problems but i have lots of dll files on my tomcat/temp folder

You can check on the next link an image that shows it:
http://prntscr.com/bvbgxm

Does anybody know how to avoid it?
Did a miss some configurations?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was reading in some forum and discovered that Its a reported bug.

https://github.com/xerial/sqlite-jdbc/issues/80